# here map pointerenter not working with polyline grupe, but tap is working

Tags: addeventlistener, heremaps, pointer-events

I try to do arrow polyline (like here https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.17/dev_guide/topics/routing.html -> Show route direction arrows). And I want to add to this routeLine pointerenter event, to make it hold and drag to add endpoints and recalculate road. But then I add pointerevents nothing happens. Tap is working, but pointerenter no. I found only one solution is use use MapEvents, but I have it imported https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js, so, as I understand this, it should work.

My code now is really simple:

```
displayOnMap(result) {

    if (result.routes.length) {
        result.routes[0].sections.forEach((section) => {
            let linestring = H.geo.LineString.fromFlexiblePolyline(section.polyline)
            let routeOutline = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
                style: {
                    lineWidth: 10,
                    strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.7)',
                    lineTailCap: 'arrow-tail',
                    lineHeadCap: 'arrow-head'
                }
            });
            let routeArrows = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
                    style: {
                        lineWidth: 10,
                        fillColor: 'white',
                        strokeColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                        lineDash: [0, 2],
                        lineTailCap: 'arrow-tail',
                        lineHeadCap: 'arrow-head'
                    }
                }
            );

            let routeLine = new H.map.Group({
                volatility: true,
                objects: [routeOutline, routeArrows]
            })

            //why pointerenter is not working?
            routeLine.addEventListener('pointerenter', function(evt) {
                console.log('test 123', evt) 
            })

            let startMarker = new H.map.Marker(section.departure.place.location)
            let endMarker = new H.map.Marker(section.arrival.place.location)
            this.routeObjects = [routeLine, startMarker, endMarker]
            this.map.addObjects(this.routeObjects)
            this.map.setCenter(section.departure.place.location)
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution. In this case addEventListener require third parameter (opt_capture) set on "true".Thanks to this group scope listen event listener.

```
        routeLine.addEventListener('pointerenter', function(evt) {
            console.log('test 123', evt) 
        }, true) //<- this true is a key
```